# install sha256sum on synology NAS

Tags: linux, package, sha256, synology

I want to execute a shell script on my NAS server (Synology). In this script I need to generate a key using sha256sum.

The problem is sha256sum is not installed on the NAS.

I have installed ipkg but ipgk install sha256sum doesn't work and I don't know what package I have to install to get it.

Usually, I'm working on Ubuntu and this function is installed with Linux.

So where can I found it compatible with DSM Linux ?

PS : For same reason, I don't know how to do to have print function too...

Comment: I have finally found the answer alone : with IPKG, I have to install md5deep. With this package I have the function sha256deep which is doing the same thing that sha256sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the answer alone : with IPKG, I have to install md5deep. With this package I have the function sha256deep which is doing the same thing that sha256sum.